# Need proc variable to be written to my talb

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table I have created to insert the results of my proc and it is running great.  I would like to add a column to my table called objectnamee and have it insert the objectname I used to run the proc.

```
create table DatasetMapping 
(
Name nvarchar(257),
Type nvarchar(16),
updated nvarchar(7),
Selected nvarchar(8),
Column sysname,
OjectName nvarchar(257)---need to add to table

);

EXEC [dbo].[Repotingdatasets] @object ='dbo.PositionReport_Quote_V3_2016';
```

I would like to have 'dbo.PositionReport_Quote_V3_2016' insert into my table as objectname.  Below is the proc I am using.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Repotingdatasets]
AS   
DECLARE @object NVARCHAR(257)

 INSERT INTO DatasetMapping
  EXEC sp_epends  @objname = @object
```

Comment: _talb_? Do you mean _table_? Also: _repoting_ or _reporting_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the table

```
alter table DatasetMapping 
add OjectName nvarchar(257) null
go
```

Then insert your data however you want. Though, i find your current method odd